# SessionStorage in IE and Edge not being cleared when opening new tab

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tabs, microsoft-edge, session-storage

I've searched how sessionStorage works and everwhere I've seen that this storage is cleared when a new tab/window is opened.

In fact, that is true for all browsers except IE and Edge...

Only in a particular case this happens, which is when right click a link and "open in a new tab". When doing this, the session storage remains when navigating under the same domain.

I don't know if this is a bug of the browser or something I'm doing wrong, but if someone ever experienced this or knows a solution for this problem I would appreciate.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: The server session persists until it times out or is forced closed. If you close then open a tab after the session timeout period has elapsed, then make a request to the sever, the session data should have been cleared.

Comment: My problem is not .net session state, but the browser window.sessionStorage which is a local storage of the browser :)

Comment: yes... window.sessionStorage v window.loacalStorage.... sessionStorage is persistant for the current session ID. localStorage is persistant over different sessions.

Comment: Any resolution to this problem ? I am also facing this issue.